# Best performance and worst performance in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I am a bit confused on this topic.

If the list is already sorted then we say the best performance is n.

and for some algorithm such as bubble sort we say worst case is n^2.

My confusion is why do we say its n^2?? how did that square come ? what are the assumption that we are making to keep a square? Why are we not giving it like O(1),  O(log n),  O(n),  O(2^n) ?? please help me understand these terms... articles, blog, lecture notes.. any wil help.

I am a beginner.

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation  and then for an analysis of insertion sort, mergesort and heapsort e.g. here: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/ (Lectures 3 and 4)

Answer (score 0):

To understand the bubble sort (or any sort, really), you need to think through the process it uses.  For instance, the bubble sort works by scanning the entire list, swapping out-of-place pairs.  At worst, it makes n - 1 swaps on the first pass, examining all n elements.  For the second pass, it is guaranteed that the last element is in order--since it would be "bubbled" down to the end.  Thus, the sort has to make at most n - 2 swaps, examining n - 1 elements, and so on.  Hence, the worst-case scenario of O(n^2).

If you can understand *how* a sort works, then you can calculate the best and worst-case scenarios.
  You can get started at Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

P.S. -- The bubble sort is pretty much the worst sort ever.  However, it performs better than others if you are sorting sorted data.

Comment: what do you mean by n - 2 swaps examining n - 1 element?

insertion sort also has O(n^2) worst case. But its stable... can you provide why they use O(n^2) as worst case in simple language.


Quick sort has worst case as O(n log n).. how and why O(n log n)..

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) implies that the algorithm (bubble sort) will, in the worst case, have to do n^2 comparisons (greater than, less than, equal to), where n is the number of items being sorted.

Comment: what do you mean by n^2 comparision? is it n * n ? why not do n * n * n comparision.

insertion sort also has O(n^2) worst case. But its stable... can you provide why they use O(n^2) as worst case in simple language. Quick sort has worst case as O(n log n).. how and why O(n log n).

Comment: For bubble sort, it is comparing every item in the array (n) to every other item in the array (n) which results in n * n or n^2 comparisons.

Quicksort actually has a worst case of O(n^2) comparisons. 

Mergesort has a worst case of O(n log n) because it compares every item (n) to log(n) other items.

Comment: Well strictly speaking, by the definition of Big-O-Notation it could just as well do c*n^2 comparisons, c being a number not dependant on n...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for .

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have following simple program  and we want to find its time complexity .

```
return_sum(n)
{
y=4

while(n>0)
{
y=y+y
n=n-1
}
return y
}
```

A computer program consists set of steps , the time complexity of a program can be thought as number of steps a program takes to solve particular problem.

Number of steps needed by return_sum() program :

```
return_sum(n)
{
y=4      // this step will take constant time say, c1, and will run only once

while(n>0)  //this step run n time , if step takes c2 time , total time is n * c2
{
y=y+y     // this step will run n-1 time , total time (n-1) * c3
n=n-1    // this step will run n-1 time , total time (n-1) * c4
}return y    // takes constant time c5, run once.
}
```

Lets add time taken by all the step to execute this program

```
    = c1 + n * c2 + (n-1) * c3 +  (n-1) * c4 +c5 
    =  n(c2 + c3 + c4 ) + (c1+ c5 - c2 - c3)
```

Where (c2 + c3 + c4 ) and (c1+ c5 - c2 - c3) are constant we can denote them as a and b .

```
   =an + b
```

This is a function of n ,

f(n)  = an+b

And this function is O(n).
So the time complexity of this program is O(n).

**Proof:**

```
f(n)  = an+b

Lets give a and b any constant values , suppose a = 100 and b = 200

Now for all sufficient large value of n >=1.
                                         100n  < 200n
 and                                    
                                         200    <  200n

                  f(n)=100n+200   < 200n + 200n
                                  < 400n                   
                                  < 400 * n             where c = 400 and n0 = 1
                              f(n)= O(n)
```

[image]

Similarly when we add all steps in insert sort we get  f'(n), which is

```
                     f'(n) = an^2+bn+c
```

**By above proof we can easily find that f'(n) = O(n^2)**

Answer (score 0):

Well lot of answers lot of text (some are great)
but not a single simple enough one for the dumb
so i try it:

in: 0,3,7,8   ... n=4  best case scenario
1. **0,3**,7,8
2. 0,**3,7**,8
3. 0,3,**7,8**
- no changes occur so its sorted ... O(n-1) -> ~O(n)

in: 8,7,3,0   ... n=4  worst case scenario
1. **7,8**,3,0
2. 7,**3,8**,0
3. 7,3,**0,8**
- change occured so do not stop yet
4. **3,7**,0,8
5. 3,**0,7**,8
6. 3,0,**7,8**
- change occured so do not stop yet
7. **0,3**,7,8
8. 0,**3,7**,8
9. 0,3,**7,8**
- no changes occur so its sorted ... O((n-1)^2) -> ~O(n^2)

Hope I did not make a silly mistake somewhere ... and it helps someone ofcourse.